# How to render direct cyclic graph in React

Tags: d3.js, graphviz, graph-visualization, d3-graphviz

I need to represent a direct cyclic graph in React.
I saw that [d3-graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz) it's a good option to represent this graph. But I need to reduce apply the transitive reduction filter.

For example, I have these paths: `A -> B`, `B -> C` and `A -> C`. Transitive reduction filter may delete path `A -> C` because it reached from the path `A -> B`, `B -> C`.
I think I can't apply tred with d3-graphviz library.

How can I reach the expected result?

I tried using the [React Flow](https://reactflow.dev/) library, but I can't reduce the transitive path.

Answer (score 1):

a comment, since you tagged `graphviz`: I can confirm that you can't do that with this library.

`graphviz`, and the cross-compiled `d3-graphviz`, are designed purely for *rendering* graphs . They don't contain functionality for serious graph manipulation (with minor exceptions like the unflatten utility).